# О вопросах к событиям

Tags: семантика

Предполагаю, что каждое событие (т.е. факт, который привлекает внимание) это явление и/или деяние.

Верно ли, что:

1) каждое деяние подразумевает вопрос "Зачем?" ("С какой целью?", "Для чего?", и т. п.), но не подразумевает вопрос "Почему?",

2) каждое явление подразумевает вопрос "Почему?" ("По какой причине?", "Из-за чего?", и т. п.) и, возможно, подразумевает вопрос "Зачем?"?.

Comment: Если душа бессмертна, то сколько же их теперь, этих душ, летает вокруг нас, грешных, а? ПОЧЕМУ и ЗАЧЕМ Господь допустил такое нерациональное использование Пространства?

Comment: Не волнуйтесь, пожалуйста, ибо вокруг Вас, "грешного", "души" не "летают" и даже не ползают.

Answer (score 1):

Мне удобно различать деяния и явления так: деяния - дела человеческие, человеками содеянные.

Явления -- дела природные, явленные природой без участия человека

Зачем - это цель, почему -- причина.

Согласен, что деяния имеют цель (с некоторой натяжкой, но люди всё же действуют, имея в виду какие-то цели)

Согласен, что явления имеют причины (их изучением занимается естествознание)

С остальным скорее не согласен.

Деяния, конечно, могут иметь причины: "Ну скажи, почему ты пошёл этой дорогой, а не той!"

Явления не имеют какой-то цели (если только вы не пантеист:))

Только в шутку мы можем сказать: "Дождик, ну зачем ты пошёл именно сейчас?"